# Trying to make an analog clock

Tags: python-3.x, kivy

Im trying to learn Kivy and I thought this would be a good project to do. 
im trying to make an analog clock using the Kivy library in python.
but I can't figure out how to make it update every second.

I've tried a couple of things I learned from tutorials. but I think im doing it wrong. im not super familiar with object-oriented programing and i think that's why it's not working.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.scatter import Scatter
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import ListProperty, ObjectProperty
from kivy.graphics.vertex_instructions import (Rectangle, Ellipse, Line)
from kivy.graphics.context_instructions import Color
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.clock import Clock
import random
import math


leline = [513.0, 1013.0, 565.2642316338267, 1010.2609476841367, 616.9558454088797, 1002.0738003669028,
          667.5084971874737, 988.5282581475767, 716.3683215379001, 969.7727288213005, 763.0, 946.0127018922193,
          806.8926261462366, 917.5084971874737, 847.5653031794291, "insert the rest of the 60 cordinates that form a perfect cercle here"]

linethick = 13

class ScatterWidget(BoxLayout):
    global x
    global y
    x = 0
    y = 1

    def simple_analog(self, *args):
        global x
        global y
        Color(1, 1, 1, 1)
        Line(points=[(Window.width / 2), (Window.height / 2),
                     leline[x], leline[y],
                     ],
             width=linethick)
        x += 2
        y += 2
        if x > 60:
            x = 0
        if y > 60:
            y = 0


class CoolClockApp(App):
    def build(self):
        Clock.schedule_interval(ScatterWidget.simple_analog, 1)
        return ScatterWidget()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    CoolClockApp().run()
```

when I run it nothing happens. the window pops up but I see no white line being drawn. im sure I made a rookie mistake somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

```
class ScatterWidget(BoxLayout):
    global x
    global y
    x = 0
    y = 1
```

Even if you want to use global variables, which you shouldn't for something like this, this isn't the way to do it. But, it at least isn't the cause of your immediate problem.

```
def simple_analog(self, *args):
    global x
    global y
    Color(1, 1, 1, 1)
    Line(points=[(Window.width / 2), (Window.height / 2),
                 leline[x], leline[y],
                 ],
         width=linethick)
    x += 2
    y += 2
    if x > 60:
        x = 0
    if y > 60:
        y = 0
```

You create a Color object and a Line object, but don't do anything that would cause them to be drawn on the screen. Instead use something like:

```
with self.canvas:
    Color(...)
    Line(...)
```

This syntax causes the Color and Line to automatically get added to the specified widget's canvas.

```
 Clock.schedule_interval(ScatterWidget.simple_analog, 1)
```

This doesn't do what you want, you're calling the simple_analog method via the class itself, not via any particular instance. It isn't causing issues right now because the code doesn't make any use of the class state, but it will break as soon as you try something non-trivial.

Instead, create an instance of the class and schedule the method of that instance:

```
def build(self):
    your_instance = SatterWidget()
    Clock.schedule_interval(your_instance.simple_analog, 1)
    return your_instance
```

Answer (score 0):

At least you have the following errors:

- For painting you must use the widget's canvas.
- If you want it to be repaid then you must update the instructions.
- Do not abuse the global variables, in this case it is better to use the Kivy properties.

Considering the above, the solution is:

```
import datetime
import math

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.graphics.context_instructions import Color
from kivy.graphics.vertex_instructions import Ellipse, Line
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget


class ClockWidget(Widget):
    radius = NumericProperty(250)

    seconds_length = NumericProperty(200)
    minutes_length = NumericProperty(150)
    hours_length = NumericProperty(100)

    seconds_linethick = NumericProperty(5)
    minutes_linethick = NumericProperty(8)
    hours_linethick = NumericProperty(12)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

        self.bind(
            size=self.recalculate_line,
            seconds_length=self.recalculate_line,
            minutes_length=self.recalculate_line,
            hours_length=self.recalculate_line,
        )

        Clock.schedule_interval(self.recalculate_line, 1)

        with self.canvas:
            Color(1, 1, 0, 1)
            self.circle = Ellipse()
            Color(1, 1, 1, 1)
            self.seconds_line = Line()
            Color(0, 0, 1, 1)
            self.minutes_line = Line()
            Color(1, 0, 0, 1)
            self.hours_line = Line()

    def recalculate_line(self, *args):
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        angle_seconds = math.pi / 2 - (now.second * 2 * math.pi / 60.0)
        angle_minutes = math.pi / 2 - (
            (now.minute + now.second / 60.0) * 2 * math.pi / 60.0
        )
        angle_hours = (
            math.pi / 2
            - (now.hour + now.minute / 60.0 + now.second / 3600.0) * 2 * math.pi / 12
        )

        self.circle.size = 2 * self.radius, 2 * self.radius
        self.circle.pos = (self.center[0] - self.radius, self.center[1] - self.radius)

        for angle, line, length, linethick in zip(
            (angle_seconds, angle_minutes, angle_hours),
            (self.seconds_line, self.minutes_line, self.hours_line),
            (self.seconds_length, self.minutes_length, self.hours_length),
            (self.seconds_linethick, self.minutes_linethick, self.hours_linethick),
        ):

            x = length * math.cos(angle)
            y = length * math.sin(angle)
            line.width = linethick

            points = [
                self.width / 2,
                self.height / 2,
                self.width / 2 + x,
                self.height / 2 + y,
            ]
            line.points = points


class CoolClockApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return ClockWidget()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    CoolClockApp().run()
```

[image]